# My thermaltake chassisV9 blackx edition support hot swap of hdd in the top bays?

Tags: hard-drive, hotswapping, chassis

I have a thermaltake chassis v9 blackx edition, can I disconnect a hard drive connected to the  top bay while the computer is on?

There is any configuration, motherboard, bios settings, or software needed for that?

Comment: This isn't a question about the case, but of the mainboard and (maybe) the drive.

Comment: That's right, after enabling AHCI in the motherboard bios I can connect and eject the drives while the PC is running